# Combined List of Figures and Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a way to have a List of tables and figures as *one* list? Currently I have

```
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
```

which generates two lists and starts a new page for each list. What I want is a list that contains Tables and Figures in the same list, numbered in sequence (i.e. the first table should get the number following the last figure at that point), Babel-compatible and KOMA-Script-compatible if possible (I use both). The example command

```
\listoffiguresandtables
```

should create something like

> **List of Figures and Tables**
>
> 1.1 A nice picture caption
>
> 1.2 Another nice picture caption
>
> 2.1 A caption of a cool table

**How to do this?**

Comment: `\let\c@table=\c@figure` will solve part of your problem: it will give a single numbering scheme for tables and figures.  Tables and figures will still be different lists.

Comment: Your question isn't clear on whether you want them numbered in the same sequence. If you do, the easiest thing is just to use `figure` environment for all cases. If that _doesn't_ do what you want could you say what you want to be different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Or `\let\figure\table\let\endtable\endfigure` ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I just use `figure` everywhere then the tables won't have "Table 2.1: [caption]" below them, but "Figure 2.1: [caption]".

Comment: @FooBar `\renewcommand\figurename{Table}\caption{.....}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, now I get what you are meaning with the numbering... Figures and Tables should be numbered in sequence. So, after the first picture "Figure 1.1" should come "Table 1.2" even if it's the *first* table. But I'd like to use both, `table` and `figure` environments, for semantical reasons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\def\table{\def\figurename{Table}\figure}
\let\endtable\endfigure
```

Should put all figures and tables in the same sequence and write Table for table captions.

The list of figures will still say list of figures, if you want to change that add

```
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures and Tables}
```

Comment: This gives me `\caption outside float` on all tables. And I assume it should mean `\let\endtable\endfigure` (instead of '\lettendtable\endfigure')?

Comment: @FooBar it would work if you did what I meant, not what I wrote:-) will fix...

Comment: I want to mention one small drawback: it doesn't work with captionof.

Comment: Note that the `\renewcommand\listfigurename` should be put just before the call to `\listoffigures`. I tried setting it in the preamble and it seemed to have no effect in my case (it might have been reset by `\begin{document}` or some package).

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron probably some babel language resetting it? In that case the official way would be to modify the babel language-specific text in the preamble, but as you say defining it just where it is used works as well

Answer (score 22):

You can use the following definition in your header:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lot}
\let\c@figure\c@table
\let\ftype@figure\ftype@table
\let\listoftableandfigures\listoftables
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables and figures}
\makeatother
```

The leads to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lot}
\let\c@figure\c@table
\let\ftype@figure\ftype@table
\let\listoftableandfigures\listoftables
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables and figures}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftableandfigures


\chapter{foo}
Text

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

Text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

Text

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

Text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{foo}
Text

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

Text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

Text

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

Text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, too, this works as well, so +1. I accepted @DavidCarlisle's answer however because it needs less code.

Comment: +1, because this solution also supports `hyperref`'s `\autoref` feature.

Comment: For me this doesn't work and results in the List of figures and tables called "list of tables"