# Combined list of tables and figures with separate numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I would like to have a list of figures and tables, together, as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120644/combined-list-of-figures-and-tables), except that figures and tables should still have separate numbering systems.  For instance, to end up with

List of Figures and Tables

- Figure 1 : a picture
- Table 1 : numbers
- Figure 2 : another picture

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have figure information saved in the same place as the tables, and hence output at the same time, by adding the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{lot}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Figures and Tables}
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{lot}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Figures and Tables}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Numbers}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

If you want that list exactly as in your example, load the `tocloft` package and add the following lines in your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5.5em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table~}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{5.5em}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{lot}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Figures and Tables}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5.5em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table~}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{5.5em}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Numbers}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: wow!  that is easy.  This is telling the endtable package to save figures in the `.lot` file, right?

Comment: @petrelharp Well, not really the `endtable` package since I've not used. But you're right, that line indicates that the `figure` info has to be saved in the `.lot` file instead of the `.lof` one.