# How to make a combined "List of Figures and Tables"?

Tags: listoffigures, listoftables

I am aware of [Combined List of Figures and Tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120644/combined-list-of-figures-and-tables), but the asker there requires *one* numbering scheme for figures and tables, which I don't want. Unfortunately, the answer seems to depend on that prerequisite.

My question is about an intended result/output like:

---

## List of figures and tables

Figure 1: Map of trees in New Orleans .................................... 3

Figure 2: Number of leaves falling leaves per day ................... 5

Table 1:   Kinds of trees ........................................................ 12

Figure 3: Air quality reduction per 1000 fallen leaves ............ 20

---

For this to work, redefining figures to be tables (or the other way around) as suggested in the link above (i.e. something like `\let\figure\table\let\endtable\endfigure`) doesn't work because it of course causes all figures to be called "Table x" as well...

Comment: No, the portion of `\caption` code which uses `\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{your caption}` must be changed either to use `lof` or `lot` then or use a completely new type `lft` (list of figures and tables), but regardless, it requires some work to do

Comment: I think I've got a very simple answer, but could you please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that I can test it on your own code?

Comment: Sorry, not "very" simple, just "reasonably" simple :-)

Answer (score 7):

This works. The code is well commented so I don't think any more comments are needed.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% To make the page shorter
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight3in

% CODE STARTS HERE
% Based on `tocloft` package
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof{figtab}{loft}{List of Figures and Tables}
\makeatletter
% Change the file extension of both lot and lof
\def\ext@figure{loft}
\def\ext@table{loft}
% Store the original `\thefigure` and `\thetable`
\let\tohe@thefigure\thefigure
\let\tohe@thetable\thetable
% Redefine them to contain a "dummy" `\tohe@list...`
\def\thefigure{\tohe@listfig\tohe@thefigure}
\def\thetable{\tohe@listtab\tohe@thetable}
% Make the two dummy commands truly dummy
\let\tohe@listfig\relax
\let\tohe@listtab\relax
% Store the original `\listoffigtab`
\let\tohe@listoffigtab\listoffigtab
% Redefine it in such a way that the dummy commands insert "Fig." or "Tab." respectively
\def\listoffigtab{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tohe@listfig{Fig.~}
  \def\tohe@listtab{Tab.~}
  \tohe@listoffigtab
  \endgroup  
}
% Change \listoffigtab spacing
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{5em}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
\makeatother
% CODE ENDS HERE

\begin{document}

\listoffigtab

% !b just to make the floats appear on the bottom of the first page
\begin{figure}[!b]
\caption{First}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!b]
\caption{Little Table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!b]
\caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive, most impressive ;-) (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The relevant command is, as 'always' `\addcontentsline`.

`figure` and `table` captions are written to a file whose extension is stored in `\ext@figure` or `\ext@table`.

In `\@caption` (the internal processor macro actually) we find:

```
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
```

The first parameter of `\@caption` is the name of the float, i.e. `figure` or `table` (usually). This can be used and patched, grabbing the `table` captions and `redirect` them to the file with extension `\ext@figure`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@caption}{%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
  {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
}{%
  \IfStrEq{#1}{table}{% Filter `table` out
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@figure\endcsname}{table}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  }%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures and Tables}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another first figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
\caption{first table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\begin{table}
\caption{Yet another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A small update after `yo'` correctly noticed that it's unclear whether it's a table or figure in the LOFT:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{30pt}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{30pt}
% Prepend the tab or fig number with a `\makebox` (for equal width) and put `Tab.` or `Fig.` in there. Change the names at will 
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\makebox[30pt][l]{Tab.}}  
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\makebox[30pt][l]{Fig.}}  


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@caption}{%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
  {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
}{%
  \IfStrEq{#1}{table}{%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@figure\endcsname}{table}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname\hfill\hspace{1em}}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  }{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{figure}{%
      \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
      {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname\hfill\hspace{1em}}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
    }{%
     \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
     {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{ \ignorespaces #2}}%
    }
  }%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures and Tables}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another first figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
\caption{first table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\begin{table}
\caption{Yet another table}
\end{table}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\begin{table}
\caption{Yet another another table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice as well. The biggest problem now is to know what is a figure and what is a table...

Comment: @yo': That's true. I think, I can add some stuff for that ;-)

Comment: @yo': Appended (or prepended ;-) Tab. and Fig. for the combined LOFT list`